# MySQL, can't use group by in simple query

Tags: mysql

i have this simple query

```
select *, FIRST(m.id), MAX(mj.meeting_day) from Member m
left join SaveWork as s on s.member_id = m.id
left join Points as mp on mp.id = s.point_id
left join Aggr as mj on mj.id = mp.aggr_id
where m.congregation_id = 2
GROUP BY m.id
```

but when i try to execute it i get

```
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near '(m.id) from Member m
left join SaveWork as s on s.member_id = m.id
left join M' in line 1
```

and i don't know why this is happening,  i think it is related to this `Expression #24 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sprawy.s.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`, and i thought when i use `FIRST` function it will resolve my problems, but that didn't happen, any help is welcome

Comment: You can't have `select *` in your query while using `GROUP BY` unless you list all of those columns affected in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Can you show me the page that discusses FIRST() in the MySQL manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - first() function is not available in mysql you can use limit instead

```
select m.id, MAX(mj.meeting_day) from Member m
left join SaveWork as s on s.member_id = m.id
left join Points as mp on mp.id = s.point_id
left join Aggr as mj on mj.id = mp.aggr_id
where m.congregation_id = 2
GROUP BY m.id order by m.id
limit 1
```

Comment: `LIMIT` without `GROUP BY` is meaningless.